# Select Value based on Multiple Value Range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am having multiple criteria to give incentive to my employees. For example as shown in below image

Grid Table is dynamic in nature. It keeps on changing based on business conditions.

[image: Click]

I have a table where I have emp Ids whose Resolution % I have calculated and also calculated their Normalization %. Now, I need to give them % Incentives based on the above Grid using SQL Query.

Output Table in which i need to update the incentives

[image: Click]

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - [mcve]. (And most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the grid table is also stored as a database table (so you can update it):

```
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------+
| INCENTIVES                                                                          |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------+
| from_resulution | to_resolution | from_normalization | to_normalization | incentive |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------+
|  0              |    70         |     0              |         5        |    9      |
|  0              |    70         |     5              |         10       |   11      |
|  0              |    70         |     10             |        100       |   13      |
|  71             |    75         |     0              |         5        |   10      |
... I hope you get the idea
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------+
```

And the update query can be:

```
update employee E
   set E.incentive = (select I.incentive
                        from incentives I
                       where e.resolution >= I.from_resolution
                         and e.resolution < I.to_resolution
                         and e.normalization >= I.from_normalization
                         and e.normalization < I.to_normalization)
```

UPDATE: the TO values are not in the scope of the range. By using the TO value equal to the FROM value of the next range we assure to cover all values (including floating point). Thanks to Gordon

Comment: You should probably be using `<` for the "to values" because these look like floating point numbers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I agree but I reused the information as described in the question. Indeed it has no values for normalization 5.5. let's adapt the answer

Comment: . . It is still better to have non-overlapping ranges for this type of comparison.

Comment: Thanks Everyone. The above query was explained very well. Folks I am new here hence I am finding it bit difficult to add / revert on comments and feedbacks. However I will learn slowly for sure :)

Comment: you can select this answer as the right one so it is clear for others who arrive on this page in the future (and I get points :) Good luck

Comment: @Conffusion, I am getting following error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @PrashantDave than you must have overlapping records in incentive. I assumed for every combination (e.resolution,e.normalization) there is only one incentive with ranges that overlap. Can you find out for which employee record you have this record and verify manually there is only one incentive which meets the criteria?

Comment: True... it got rectified and solved... thx v much. Where is the option to mark your ans as right ans.. I will update it accordingly.